# Please explain this logic proposition

Tags: logic

Need some help understanding how to simplify:

\begin{align*}
(p\wedge(p\to q))\to q
\end{align*}

The answer is:

- transform the brackets into $(p\wedge q) \to q$
- using properties ends up in $(p\wedge q)' \vee q$
- $p' \vee q' \vee q$
- $p' \vee T \Longleftrightarrow V$

I can't apply any identity on the first step. How is step 1 applying identity?

I can't seem to understand how that uses identity.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: transformed p=>q into (p' v q) ended up with p ∧ (p' v q) => q

Comment: Could you put your effort into the body of the question?

Comment: I edited the post so it's more readable and understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, notice that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\vee q$.

According to such identity, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
(p\wedge(p\to q))\to q & \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge(\neg p\vee q)) \to q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ((p\wedge\neg p)\vee(p\wedge q))\to q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge q)\to q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\wedge q)\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg q)\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee(\neg q\vee q)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee\top
\end{align*}

where the last expression is a tautology.

Hopefully this helps !